# Any suggestions on how to structure backend and frontend application in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I have done one small project with Zend.
This is my second project and i will need to make a front end and a backend.
Any suggestions on how to structure the folders?
And how can i tell zend what folder if for the front end and what is for the backend as there is only one variable for that in the application.ini : resources.frontController.controllerDirectory ?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use modules. The default module for the "front end" and an "admin" module for the "back end".

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html

For configuration, use the available application resource plugins

- [Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller)
- [Zend_Application_Resource_Modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.modules)

You can bootstrap specific modules by placing a `Bootstrap.php` file in the module directory with class `ModuleName_Bootstrap`. Matthew Weier O'Phinney has written on the topic of module bootstrapping here - http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html

Your `public/index.php` should not change at all.

Comment: Do you have a better example then Zend Documentation?

Comment: @Atef Is there something that's not clear from the Zend doco?

Comment: an example that talks about everything else: application.ini, Bootstrap, and public/index.php